# Responsive contact/application form

Tags: html

I have an application form that users answer questions on and am looking for some responsiveness. Basically what I am looking for is some way so that if the user checks something like

Other

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Other" value="Other" />
    </div>
    <label>Other</label>
</div>
```

Then and only then it shows

```
<div>
    <label>If other, which game(s)?</label>
    <textarea name="Other Response"></textarea>
</div>
```

Thank you! I've got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially you can create textarea content with display:'none' property, so that the  not visible to the user and you can show the part of other Content HTML element, when he checks the other checkbox.

Check the working code here,

```
**HTML**
<div class="userCheck">
 <input type="checkbox" id="other" name="Other" value="Other" />
 <label>Other</label>
</div>

<div class="otherCon">
 <label>If other, which game(s)?</label>
 <textarea name="Other Response"></textarea>
</div>

**CSS**
.otherCon {
  visibility: hidden;
}

**JS**
$('#other').on('click', function() {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $('.otherCon').css('visibility', 'visible');
 } else {
   $('.otherCon').css('visibility', 'hidden');
 }
});
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to adjust the rest of the content so that there isn't a big break where the hidden content is when the box is unchecked and then when the box is check it scroll the rest of the content down?

Comment: You have to format the form structure clearly, show me the code what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you pls upvote my answer, if you are accepting and think that is useful for you.